# WININET.InternetConnect fails in Windows 8

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-8, wininet

This code worked well on Win7 but fails with unknown error `0x2f8c` in Windows 8 (Release Preview). Any idea why? Note that I checked out the code, compiled and ran it, but I'm pretty sure I got all dependencies right. The win32 declaration:

```
   [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        extern public static IntPtr InternetConnect(
            [In] IntPtr hInternet,
            [In] string serverName,
            [In] int serverPort,
            [In] string userName,
            [In] string password,
            [In] int dwService,
            [In] int dwFlags,
            [In] IntPtr dwContext);
```

Comment: That's ERROR_INTERNET_NOT_INITIALIZED so I would look further up at your InternetOpen call

Comment: Ahhhh, my bad, I found some errors in my code of course which resulted in InternetOpen not being called! Thanks! Alex, if you add this as an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's `ERROR_INTERNET_NOT_INITIALIZED` so I would look further up at your `InternetOpen` call  for the problem.